# Obtaining momentum operator $P^\mu$ from Lagrangian and energy-momentum tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am pretty new to quantum field theory. Given the Lagrangian density,
$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} ( \partial_\mu \phi ) ( \partial^\mu \phi ) - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2
$$
and its energy-momentum tensor
$$
T^{\mu \nu} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu \phi) } \partial^\nu \phi - g^{\mu \nu} \mathcal{L} 
$$
I would like to obtain $P^\mu$. I already know that 
$$ P^j = \int d^3 x \pi_r(x) \frac{\partial \phi_r(x)}{\partial x_j} $$
and 
$$ \pi_r(x) = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\phi_r}} ,$$
but I do not really know how to calculate $P^\mu$. Anybody has some advice how to start?

Comment: I'd put $P^\mu = T^{\mu0}$

Comment: @Phoenix87 - Rather $P^\nu = \int d^3 x T^{0\nu}$

Comment: @Prahar agreed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The momentum is given by $P^\mu = (E,\vec{P})$, and the operator acting as $[:P^\mu:,a^\dagger_k] = k^\mu a^\dagger_k$.

Energy is an eigenvalue of the Hamiltonian, which is given by $H = \int d^3x~T^{00}$ and $\vec{P}$ is given by your relation above, which from the definition of the stress energy tensor also equals
$$P^j = \int d^3x~T^{0j}$$

You can combine these to give
$$ P^\mu = \int d^4x~T^{0\mu}$$

which can be calculated from the definition of the stress energy tensor you gave.